# Unable to install pandas or other packages in linux virtual environment

Tags: python, pandas

I am unable to install module pandas in my linux vm. I tried all ways to install it, but it says it has version 1.1.5 requirement already satistied. But when I try running the code, it says, no module found. The latest version of python in it is 2.7.3, but I want to install 3.8 or 3.7, but I'm unable to. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In your terminal, if you run `python3` does it run a python console and what version is it running?

Comment: It says no package python3.0 available

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing python3 from your package manager? You can install python 3.9 from apt using the below command

`apt install python3 pip -y`

You can also install the below package to use python in the terminal instead of python3 every time

`apt install python-is-python3 -y`

I cant comment yet so using the answer section, kindly give me an upvote so I can start using the comment feature, sorry for the trouble

Comment: Yeah. It is not recognizing apt.

Comment: Alternatively, you can install python using tarball
https://opensource.com/article/20/4/install-python-linux